# SSIS - Add a numbered row at the top of the Excel destination

Tags: excel, ssis, insert, row

I created an SSIS project which exports a table from a database to an excel file. Now I would like to add a line at the top of my file (numbered 1 to 130) so that it looks like this.

[image: Excel screen]

Is this possible with SSIS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While I remember facing the same needed task once, this is the trick I used it may not be optimized but it was a workaround that I implemented :

You need to specify the range beside the Sheet Name:

```
addingYouRow = "Insert into [" + sheetname + "A1:X1] values('1','2',...)"
```